# Significance of SIGINT and signal15

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

What type of common attribute do *signal15* and *SIGINT* belong to? Is there any command to see these attributes?

Comment: Read about kill command.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know more about these signals? `man 7 signal` or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: The kill -l command shows all the signal numbers and commands including the above. Was looking for this. Thanks!